# Adding PointSeries to Plotters plot in Rust

Tags: rust, charts

I am trying to generate a plot with both line and point series using plotters. I have got the chart successfully displaying a line series, however the point series throws a bunch of errors. An abbreviated version of the code I am using for the point series is as follows. I think the problem is how I am specifying the point size but I am not sure how to do it correctly. Any assistance would be great!

```
fn main() {
    let points: Vec<(f64, f64)> = vec![(2.0, 2.0), (3.0, 3.0 ), (4.0, 4.0), (8.0, 8.0)];
    generate_plot(&points);
}


fn generate_plot(points: &Vec<(f64, f64)>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let root = BitMapBackend::new("C:\\Users\\ppp\\Documents\\Rust\\tpy\\Data\\test.png", (800, 800)).into_drawing_area();
    root.fill(&WHITE)?;
    let mut chart = ChartBuilder::on(&root)
       .build_cartesian_2d(0f64..10f64, 0f64..10f64)?;
    chart.configure_mesh().draw()?;
    chart.draw_series(PointSeries::new(points.clone(), 5, &BLUE))?;  //This does not work. I can get a line series to plot without issue.
    root.present()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

**Errors:**

> error[E0282]: type annotations needed   --> src\main.rs:29:11    | 29
> |     chart.draw_series(PointSeries::new(points.clone(), 5, &BLUE))?;
> //This does not work. I can get a line series to plot without issue.
> |           ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `B`
> declared on the associated function `draw_series`    | help: consider
> specifying the generic arguments    | 29 |     chart.draw_series::<B,
> E, R, plotters::series::PointSeries<'_, (f64, f64), Vec<(f64, f64)>,
> E, i32>>(PointSeries::new(points.clone(), 5, &BLUE))?;  //This does
> not work. I can get a line series to plot without issue.    |
> +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>
> error[E0283]: type annotations needed   --> src\main.rs:29:23    | 29
> |     chart.draw_series(PointSeries::new(points.clone(), 5, &BLUE))?;
> //This does not work. I can get a line series to plot without issue.
> |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type of the type
> parameter `E` declared on the struct `PointSeries`    |    = note:
> multiple `impl`s satisfying `_: PointElement<(f64, f64), i32>` found
> in the `plotters` crate:
> - impl<Coord, Size> PointElement<Coord, Size> for Circle<Coord, Size>
> where Size: SizeDesc;
> - impl<Coord, Size> PointElement<Coord, Size> for Pixel
> where Size: SizeDesc;
> - impl<Coord, Size> PointElement<Coord, Size> for TriangleMarker<Coord, Size>
> where Size: SizeDesc;
> - impl<Coord, Size> PointElement<Coord, Size> for plotters::element::Cross<Coord, Size>
> where Size: SizeDesc; note: required by a bound in `plotters::series::PointSeries::<'a, Coord, I, E, Size>::new`   -->
> C:\Users\ppp.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\plotters-0.3.4\src\series\point_series.rs:27:8
> | 27 |     E: PointElement<Coord, Size>,    |
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in
> `plotters::series::PointSeries::<'a, Coord, I, E, Size>::new` help:
> consider specifying the type argument in the function call    | 29 |
> chart.draw_series(PointSeries::new::(points.clone(), 5, &BLUE))?;
> //This does not work. I can get a line series to plot without issue.
> |                                       +++++

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).